# Bash String Remove Specific Characters

Tags: php, regex, bash, replace

I'm almost done with using bash, but the last thing I need to do is to do a regex replace on a string in bash. I have the PHP equivalent here

```
preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\.]/", '',$theme_name);
```

I need to do this exact same thing in bash, which is replacing every non alphanumeric character or dots (.) with nothing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
echo "some string" | tr -d -c ".[:alnum:]"
```

- `tr` "translates" characters in the string
- `-d` deletes instead of translates
- `-c` means complement
- `[:alnum:]` means "alpha numerics".

Comment: How could I make a string equal to that?

Comment: use backtics: `newstr='echo "..." | tr ...'`   (but replace `'` with backticks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```sh
echo "hello world" | sed  -e 's/[reg_ex]//g'
```